# xmpp connect anonymous to resource

Tags: xmpp, exp

I am writing an xmpp-ice tunnel for ssh (any tcp really). I would like to give every ssh host a different resource

```
account@xmpp.example.com/host1
account@xmpp.example.com/host2
...
```

And since ssh already has authentication I don't want to do that. Even an anonymous login should be able to make a connection, so you wouldn't need to know every clients xmpp account to add them to the roaster.

On normal xmpp servers i can just send a message to a resource. However, for gmail this doesn't work as it changes the resource name

Is there a way for a jid to exchange information with a specific client of an other jid such that

- there is no need for a presence subscription (I think things like xep-30 require this)
- it is not noticeable to any real users of the account (without this you could simply write to the bar jid)